# Default construct std::optional of unknown value_type

Tags: c++, constructor, option-type

```
auto Lambda=[](auto& opt) {
    opt=<default constructor of opt::value_type>;
};

std::optional<std::string> optstr;
Lambda(optstr);
std::optional<int> optint;
Lambda(optint);
```

Here I want `Lambda` to be able to initialize `opt` ... but I can't say `std::string()` because then when it's called with `int` I'll have an error.

I've tried `decltype` but couldn't get it to compile.

Comment: How exactly did `decltype` not work? Please present a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
auto temp = typename std::decay_t<decltype(opt)>::value_type{};
```

inside your lambda. Or:

```
auto temp = typename std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(opt)>::value_type{};
```

in C++20.

`decltype(opt)` alone doesn't work, since you pass `opt` by reference, therefore its type is a reference to `std::optional`. You therefore need to remove that reference from resulting type to get access to the `std::optional` itself, and then to its `value_type`.

---

It's the same as in the following code:

```
std::optional<int>& o;
decltype(o)::value_type i{}; // error
```

or even:

```
std::optional<int>&::value_type i{}; // error
```

Comment: Ok I was missing the `typename` and the `decay_t`.  Can you add an explanation/link to the answer explaining why they are necessary?  Then I will accept.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash Updated.